# Create a one week agenda in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm starting studying python and in particular I'm starting studying the dictionary. I saw an exercise and I decide to solve it. The exercise asks to create a one week agenda in python using dictionaries. Nothing too complicate but I have also to insert the appointment that the user wants to insert. I create something, not too difficult, but I don't know how to create a design of the agenda. I did something:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
line_new = ''
d = {}
d = OrderedDict([("Monday", "10.30-11.30: Sleeping"), ("Tuesday", "13.30-15.30: Web Atelier"), ("Wednsday", "08.30-10.30: Castle"), ("Thursday", ""), ("Friday", "11.30-12.30: Dinner"), ("Saturday",""), ("Sunday","")])
for key in d.keys():
    line_new = '{:>10}\t'.format(key)
    print(line_new)
print("|               |                          |                              |                          |                      |                 |                       |")
print("|               |                          |                              |                          |                      |                 |                       |")
print("|               |                          |                              |                          |                      |                 |                       |")
```

Where the output is:

Monday
Tuesday
Wednsday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday

And the lines to create the idea of a table. How can I put the days all on one line using dictionary? I know how to do it with strings (with format) but I don't know how to do it with the keys od the dictionary
Can you help me?

EDIT
The output I'm looking for is something like:

```
Monday       Tuesday     Wednesday   Thursday     Friday    Saturday    Sunday

|           |          |             |         |          |           |        |
|           |          |             |         |          |           |        |
|           |          |             |         |          |           |        |
|           |          |             |         |          |           |        |
```

With some space more between the days (I cannot insert it here) And the lines that create a division between the days

[image: Update to the output after Wasosky's solution]

Update to the output after Wasowsky's solution

Comment: can you show what you are going to do? (expected output)

Comment: Oh right. I'm sorry. The output should be the day of the week printed on one line with some space in between to divide the days. Basically the same thing .format() does

Comment: Please just edit your question and add one or two lines that correspond to your sample data. I don't understand how you want to print a day of the week with spaces to divide the days... Just show it.

Comment: I tried to do my best for a better editing

Answer (score 0):

```
# you can save your formatting as a string to stay consistent
fmt = '{txt:>{width}}' 

# calculate how much space you need instead of guessing:
maxwidth = max(len(day) for day in d.keys()) 

# join formatted strings with your separator and print
separator = '   '
print separator.join(fmt.format(txt=day, width=maxwidth) for day in d.keys())

# you can use the same formatter to print other rows, just change separator
separator = ' | '
for _ in range(3):
    print ' | '.join(fmt.format(txt='', width=maxwidth) for day in d.keys())
```

Output:

```
  Monday    Tuesday   Wednsday   Thursday     Friday   Saturday     Sunday
         |          |          |          |          |          |         
         |          |          |          |          |          |         
         |          |          |          |          |          |
```

Comment: Ok. It works but I have a different output. The problem is about the line. Look at my edit

Comment: It looks like you are using variable width font, that's why they do not align. Switch to monospaced font family.

Comment: But your console has a different font family, so even though it is aligned character-wise, pixels do not align

Comment: aaaaah the font of the console. Ok. I thought the font of the code. I'll try to solve it. Thanks